# Which specific tasks do fall under "Project Support" activity?

Tags: tasks, management, task-management

I need some advice on what tasks can fall under "Project Support" activity in a similar way that we can say the following fall under "Project Development"

- Requirement gathering
- coding
- testing

Comment: What are the obstacles to implementing the solution you propose?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title is about listing a series of tasks but your question text is about how to add the tasks to a category of product support. Could you match your title with the question text to make it clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the project, and the SLA (Service Level Agreement) that has been agreed, these activities could include:

- Client training.
- Bug fixing.
- Minor tweaks.
- A/B Testing.
- Further feature development.
- Quarterly Security Reviews.
- PCI Compliance Support.

At the end of the day, any work that goes into the project after it has been launched could be deemed as 'Project Support'.